# How to stop the script if a condition is met?

Tags: pine-script

(P.S. I had a similar question, but I deleted it and wrote this simplified one)

The script have a starting point from where it start to search for conditions, from this point I need when any of those 3 conditions is met first, to stop plotting anything from that point, inclusive if the same condition is met again in the future.

For the dummy script I used 3 EMA crossovers for each of those 3 conditions, so if `close` will cross `ema50` first, there should be no more cross plots in the future for any of them, basically the script should stop right there.

This is the farthest I could get, my way of doing it is not plotting anything.

Edit: I updated the script according to LucF answer, which work well (no plots or plotshapes plotted after one of those 3 conditions is met, but still I need that first condition/plotshape to be plotted on the chart.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

//time reset
ttt = input(title = "Date", defval = timestamp("25 Apr 2021 00:00 +0000"), type = input.time, inline = "time")
tz = input(0, title="TimeZone", type=input.integer, inline = "time")

timeadj = time + tz * 60 * 60 * 1000
t1 = timeadj >= ttt ? 1 : 0
bgcolor(t1 ? color.new(color.aqua, 95) :na)

//emas
ema50  = ema(close, 50)
ema100 = ema(close, 100)
ema200 = ema(close, 200)

//conditions
bool ema50_cross = crossover(close, ema50) and t1
bool ema100_cross = crossover(close, ema100) and t1
bool ema200_cross = crossover(close, ema200) and t1
var bool stopPlotting = false
stopPlotting := stopPlotting or ema50_cross or ema100_cross or ema200_cross

//plots
plot(not stopPlotting ? ema50  :na, color = color.yellow)
plot(not stopPlotting ? ema100 :na, color = color.purple)
plot(not stopPlotting ? ema200 :na, color = color.aqua)

//plotshapes
plotshape(not stopPlotting ? ema50_cross :na, color = color.yellow, size = size.small)
plotshape(not stopPlotting ? ema100_cross :na, color = color.purple, size = size.small)
plotshape(not stopPlotting ? ema200_cross :na, color = color.aqua, size = size.small)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will stop plotting whenever one of your crosses occur:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

ema50  = ema(close, 50)
ema100 = ema(close, 100)
ema200 = ema(close, 200)

bool ema50_cross = crossover(close, ema50)
bool ema100_cross = crossover(close, ema100)
bool ema200_cross = crossover(close, ema200)
var bool stopPlotting = false
stopPlotting := stopPlotting or ema50_cross or ema100_cross or ema200_cross

plot(not stopPlotting ? ema50  :na, color = color.yellow)
plot(not stopPlotting ? ema100 :na, color = color.purple)
plot(not stopPlotting ? ema200 :na, color = color.aqua)
    
plotshape(ema50_cross, color = color.yellow, size = size.small)
plotshape(ema100_cross, color = color.purple, size = size.small)
plotshape(ema200_cross, color = color.aqua, size = size.small)
```

Comment: I added the time reset to your script and indeed, it stop plotting when any of those 3 conditions is met first, but I need to have that first plotshape(cross) on the chart, I followed your example for all 3 plotshapes `plotshape(not stopPlotting ? ema50_cross :na, color = color.yellow, size = size.small)`...same for the other two, but this way will stop plotting all plotshapes, inclusive the first one, which I want to be plotted.

Comment: You're welcome. You didn't mention that requirement in your initial question. Add an edit at the end of your question with a compilable snippet if you want more help.

Comment: Ok, I played a little bit with your code and I added indexes to the conditions from the line `stopPlotting := s...` , changed with `stopPlotting := stopPlotting or ema50_cross[1] or ema100_cross[1] or ema200_cross[1]` and aparently it's working, it will show only the first condition/plotshape that is met and never repeat it, but I'm not sure if it's the best way of doing it. Anyway, thanks again, learned something new, if there is no other way, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: That should work fine, but will make your MAs stop plotting one bar later. Could also use the previous instance of `stopPlotting` with `stopPlotting[1]` only in your `plotshape()` tests.